# Sort table unique parameters

Tags: r

I have a table called `myTable` (input) :

```
 user_name   session_num  
1     "Joe"            1    
2     "Tom"            2    
3    "Fred"            1    
4     "Tom"            1    
5     "Joe"            2    
6     "John"           1
```

I want to know how many of my  `user_id` have **only**  `session_num = 1` (output) :

```
   user_name   session_num   
1     "Fred"             1
2     "John"             1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(all(session_num == 1)) .SD, by = user_name]
#    user_name session_num
# 1:      Fred           1
# 2:      John           1
```

Another option is to try an anti join

```
df[session_num == 1][!df[session_num != 1], on = "user_name"]
#    user_name session_num
# 1:      Fred           1
# 2:      John           1
```

Comment: You may also want to read [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) in order to get more comfortable with `data.table`

Answer (score 5):

A comparable solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
myTable %>%
  group_by(user_name) %>%
  filter(all(session_num == 1))
```

which gives:

```
  user_name session_num
     (fctr)       (int)
1      Fred           1
2      John           1
```

Comment: Error: could not find function "%>%" (dplyr installed)

Comment: Which version of `dplyr` do you have? Or maybe you forgot to load with `library(dplyr)`? (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks man it works! Last question - How can get this result in the table?

Comment: @Smasell just put `myNewTable <-` in front `myTable`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively we could simply exclude all users that have a session number other than `1`, using `base` R.

```
# User's with session number other than 1
two <- myTable$user_name[myTable$session_num != 1] 

# Exclude them
myTable[!myTable$user_name %in% two,]
#  user_name session_num
#3      Fred           1
#6      John           1
```

Comment: Interestingly we thought about this pretty much at the same time. Though I think using `!=1` instead of `==2` is safer in order to cover all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2 line answer:

```
library(data.table)
data1<-fread("test.csv")
data1[user_name == names(which(table(data1$user_name)==1)),][session_num==1,]
```

First it goes and looks at who is in the dataset only once and then secondly  subsets on those where `session_num==1`.

Comment: If you replace the `==` with `%in%` after `user_name` you get the expected result. With the latest official release of data.table (v1.9.6) the code throws an error.

Comment: Not sure which of the `data.table` specific features this answer uses.